# Electric field at a point

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, homework-and-exercises

> We consider a thin disk whose center is $O$ and radius is $R$, which has an electric surface charge density of $\sigma$. We want to find the expression of the electric field $\vec{E}$ at a point $M$ of
> the $(O_z)$ axis using the definition of an electric field at a point, where $(O_z)$ is perpendicular to the disk. The altitude of $M$ from the disk is $z$.

Let $\vec{k}$ be the unit vector in $(O_z)$.

I first calculated the potential $V$ at $M$ and then used the relation $\vec{E}=-\vec{grad}V$ and found that: $$\vec{E}=\dfrac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon _0}\left( 1-\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}\right)\vec{k}$$

I checked this answer on the internet. It's correct.

Now I'll calculate it using the definition. Here I find a problem: the result is different. Using symeterie it's physically clear that $\vec{E}$ is a vector in $(O_z)$ and that's confirmed by the formula $\vec{E}=\dfrac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon _0}\left( 1-\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}\right)\vec{k}$. However using this different reasoning I get a totally different result.

---

### The alternative reasoning

[image: Schema]

According to the definition we have $d\vec{E}=\dfrac{dq}{4\pi\varepsilon _0 MP^2}\vec{u}=\dfrac{\sigma\,dS}{4\pi\varepsilon _0 MP^2}\vec{u}$ where $||\vec{u}||=1$

We have $\cos\theta =\dfrac{z}{MP}$ so $\dfrac{1}{MP^2}=\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{z^2}$ and $dS=r\,dr\,d\phi$ in the polar coordinate system.

So $\vec{E}=\dfrac{\sigma\cos^2\theta\,r\,dr\,d\phi}{4\pi\varepsilon _0z^2}\vec{u}$

And $\tan\theta=\dfrac{r}{z}$ so $r=z\tan\theta$ and $dr=\dfrac{z}{\cos^2\theta}d\theta$

So $d\vec{E}=\dfrac{\sigma\tan\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi}{4\pi\varepsilon _0}\vec{u}$

Consider $\vec{j}$ the unit vector from $O$ to the right. We have: $$\vec{u}=\cos\theta\vec{j}+\sin\theta\vec{k}\tag{1}$$

So:

$$\vec{E}=\dfrac{\sigma}{4\pi\varepsilon _0}\left( \left(\iint\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\right)\vec{j}+\left(\iint\tan\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\right)\vec{k}\right)$$

The first formula I found contains only $\vec{k}$, but in this last formula I have:

$$\left(\iint\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\right)\vec{j}=\left( \int\limits_0^{2\pi}d\phi\right)\left(\int\limits_0^{\theta_{max}}\sin\theta\,d\theta\right)\vec{j}\neq \vec{0}$$

---

I'm totally confused. This reasoning isn't false, so was my use of the polar coordinate systeme valid? And the choosen integrating domains is also valid?

---

### Edit:

I found that I've made a mistake: $\vec{u}=\sin\theta\vec{j}+\cos\theta\vec{k}$. The relation $(1)$ is false.

But I'm still confused. We still find that $\vec{E}$ isn't on $(O_z)$:

---

### Rectifying:

We have then:$$\vec{E}=\dfrac{\sigma}{4\pi\varepsilon _0}\left(\left(\iint\tan\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\right)\vec{j}+ \left(\iint\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\right)\vec{k}\right)$$

Notice that:

$$\dfrac{\sigma}{4\pi\varepsilon _0}\left(\iint\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\right)\vec{k}=\dfrac{\sigma}{4\pi\varepsilon _0}\left( \int\limits_0^{2\pi}d\phi\right)\left(\int\limits_0^{\theta_{max}}\sin\theta\,d\theta\right)\vec{k}=\dfrac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon _0}\left( 1-\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}\right)\vec{k}$$

because $\cos\theta_{max}=\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}$. That's exactly the first formula we got.

But the problem is that we should then get:$$\left(\iint\tan\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi\right)\vec{j}=\vec{0}$$

which means that:$$\int\limits_0^{\theta_{max}}\tan\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta=0\tag{2}$$

While $\theta_{max}\in \left]0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right[$ it's mathematically clear that $(2)$ isn't correct because:$$\int\limits_0^{\theta_{max}}\tan\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta>0$$

---

After thinking, I found that I must introduce another vector essential to find exactly $\vec{u}$ which is $\vec{i}$ such as $\vec{i}\wedge\vec{j}=\vec{k}$ because if we look at the schema without rotating if we take the point where is wroten $\sigma$ then $\vec{u}$ isn't a vector of $(O,\vec{j},\vec{k})$. The coordinate related to $\vec{k}$ will not change but the one related to $\vec{j}$ will change.

What do you think about that?

---

## Edit2:

Going from spheric to cartesian coordonate system we get $\vec{u}=\vec{e_r}=\cos\theta\vec{k}+\sin\theta\cos\phi\vec{i}+\sin\theta\sin\phi\vec{j}$. Here $\theta$ and $\phi are exactly the same we used previously.

We have:$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sin\phi\,d\phi=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\cos\phi\,d\phi=0$$

So finally by subtitution we get:$$\vec{E}=\dfrac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon _0}\left( 1-\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}\right)\vec{k}$$ which is the same formula we got using the first reasoning.

Comment: Hi Scientifica, and welcome to Physics.SE! Please take a moment to read [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).

Comment: Ok I'm reading it right now. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: Please note that *check my work*-type questions are off-topic on this site, falling under the homework policy (even if they arise from something else than an academic assignment).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not a check my work question because I know that it's false and I'm asking why it's false.

Comment: No really, this is a "check my work" question as in "check my work and show me my mistake".  However, if you're convinced your math is correct and can phrase the question as something like *is my reasoning in step c valid?* then I think your question will be received better.

Comment: Well I used the polar coordonate system for the points of the disk, so $r$ is the distance between a point $P$ of the disk and its origin $O$.
What makes me more confused after your comment is that to calculate the potential $V$ at $M$ to use $\vec{E}=-\vec{grad}V$ I used same reasoning and used $dV=\dfrac{dq}{4\pi\varepsilon_0\,MP}$ and choosed the polar system, but the result was correct.

Comment: I noticed one thing: $\vec{u}=\sin\theta\vec{j}+\cos\theta\vec{k}$ not what I wrote. I'm going to calculate again! So the problem comes from $\vec{u}$

Comment: I totally solved the problem. Look at Edit2